# Twitter bootstrap thumbnails offsets

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I'm having a problem with thumbnails not collapsing correctly, and the code:
https://gist.github.com/4676514

Not sure why that 5th thumbnail is collpasing to the right, and why it wouldn't start a new row?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is this solved? I try to use javascript to adjust the height of each element on $(window).load event. It works for chrome, but not for firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try replicating the layout that they use in the Bootstrap examples and see if that works?

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#thumbnails

```
<div class="row">
  <ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="span3">
      <img src="">
      <div class="caption">TEXT</div>
    </li>
    <li class="span3">
      <img src="">
      <div class="caption">TEXT</div>
    </li>
    <li class="span3">
      <img src="">
      <div class="caption">TEXT</div>
    </li>
    <li class="span3">
      <img src="">
      <div class="caption">TEXT</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is basically what I am doing already, and that behaves the same.

Comment: Can you link to your development site?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are trying to load all the image tiles under one `<div class="row">`

Rather than doing that way create a separate row for each of the image rows.

First row:

```
<div class ="row">
  <div class="span3">image1</div>
  <div class="span3">image2</div>
  <div class="span3">image3</div>
</div>
```

For 2nd row:

```
<div class ="row">
  <div class="span3">image4</div>
  <div class="span3">image5</div>
  <div class="span3">image6</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: If i split them up in rows of 3 it will work fine but it leaves a huge unwanted gap.  If i split them into rows of 4, it does the same behavior, which I don't understand, the first element of that 2nd row should start on the left?  but it looks exactly the same.